# Can you programmatically release all wakelocks on a Samsung mobile device

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I am writing a Samsung mobile device kiosk application where it resumes itself, if it has been paused, after the screen turns off.

The application itself can be paused to allow user's to explore the phone and user's can even install apps and try them out.

The problem occurs if the user installs and runs an application that does not release its wakelock properly (or the application is left running), as the screen will then not turn off and my application will not resume.

Is there some service I can write, or anything, that would periodically release any wakelocks that have been acquired by other applications?